# What is the difference between futures::select! and tokio::select?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I'm using Tokio and I want to receive requests from two different `mpsc` queues. `select!` seems like the way to go, but I'm not sure what the difference is between `futures::select!` and `tokio::select!`. Under which circumstances one should you use one over the other?

Comment: I don't think this is important

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`tokio::select!` was built out of experiences with `futures::select!`, but improves a bit on it to make it more ergonomic. E.g. the `futures-rs` version of `select!` requires `Future`s to implement `FusedFuture`, whereas Tokio's version no longer requires this.

Instead of this, Tokio's version supports preconditions in the macro to cover the same use-cases.

The [PR in the tokio repo](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/pull/2152) elaborates a bit more on this.

This change was also [proposed for the futures-rs version](https://github.com/rust-lang/futures-rs/issues/1989), but has not been implemented there so far.

If you already have Tokio included in your project, then using Tokio's version seems preferable. But if you have not and do not want to add an additional dependency, then the futures-rs version will cover most use-cases too in a nearly identical fashion. The main difference is that some `Future`s might need to be converted into `FusedFuture`s through the `FutureExt::fuse()` extension method.

Answer (score 4):

To complement @matthias247's answer, a related big difference is that `futures::select!` takes futures in branch expressions [by mutable reference](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/06_multiple_futures/03_select.html#interaction-with-unpin-and-fusedfuture), so uncompleted futures can be re-used in a loop.

`tokio::select!`, on the other hand, [consumes](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/wait-for-futures-in-loop/43007/2) passed futures. To get behavior similar to `futures::select!` you need to explicitly pass a reference (e.g. `&mut future`),  and pin it if necessary (e.g. if it is `async fn`). Tokio docs have a section on this, [Resuming an async operation](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/select#resuming-an-async-operation)

[This thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-doesnt-tokio-select-require-fusedfuture/46975/1) has an in-depth explanation of why Tokio decided not to use `FusedFuture`.